# Physics-enabled sprites are shaking when applying velocity

Tags: c++, visual-c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I have a simple c++ class that inherited from Sprite. It has a PhysicsBody (using default physic engine). In the update method of this class i apply some velocity to it:

```
void PhysicsBodySprite::update()
{
    ...
    Vec2 velocity;
    velocity.x = 0;
    velocity.y = 100;
    this->getPhysicsBody()->setVelocity(velocity);
    ...
}
```

When i use version 3.3 of cocos2d it has not any problem, but in v3.5 and v3.7 it is shaking a little!
When i use Box2D there is no problem.

I use C++ under Visual Studio 2013 and build project as win32 project.

Comment: Shaking in the direction of movement (stuttering) or perpendicular to it?

Comment: In the direction of movement.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's in the direction of motion, it sounds like a vertical sync issue. Try disabling that if possible in the engine settings.

Check also when you're updating, and add a breakpoint and figure out if your movement/update is getting called multiple times.

Comment: I apply some diagonal velocity and the shake in the direction of motion is still remains, but i`ll do everything you said ...

Comment: Adding diagonal velocity won't change the fact that there is vertical frame rendering i.e. likely vertical sync